# Is there react-native custom checkbox available?

Tags: checkbox, react-native

I am trying to add checkbox in my app. I found a checkbox but they uses images for **checkbox**. I could not change the color of it. I could not find any proper checkbox in **react-native**.

Is there any custom checkbox available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used this plugin for my app.
It is very easy to install.

[ReactNativeEasyCheckbox](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-easy-checkbox)

hope it will help you.

Comment: Thank you Harish.

Answer (score 1):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components'
import { TouchableOpacity, View } from 'react-native'
const CustomCheckBox = styled(View)`
  height: 24px;
  width: 24px;
  background: ${props => (props.checkBoxActive ? '#448ccb' : 'transparent')};
  border-radius: 0px;
  position: relative;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0px 8px 0 0;
  border: solid 1px #e1e4e5;
`
const CheckIcon = styled(View)`
  border-radius: 0px;
  align-self: center;
  transform: rotate(-30deg);
`
/*==============================
    Custom  checkbox styled 
===============================*/
const CheckIconWrapper = styled(View)`
  position: relative;
  left: 2px;
  top: -2px;
`
const CheckIconVertical = styled(View)`
  height: 5px;
  width: 2px;
  background: ${props => (props.checkBoxActive ? '#fff' : 'transparent')};
`
const CheckIconHorizontal = styled(View)`
  height: 2px;
  width: 16px;
  background: ${props => (props.checkBoxActive ? '#fff' : 'transparent')};
`
class CheckBox extends Component {
  state = {
    checkBox: false
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => {
          this.setState({ checkBox: !this.state.checkBox })
        }}>
        <CustomCheckBox checkBoxActive={this.state.checkBox}>
          <CheckIcon>
            <CheckIconWrapper>
              <CheckIconVertical checkBoxActive={this.state.checkBox} />
              <CheckIconHorizontal checkBoxActive={this.state.checkBox} />
            </CheckIconWrapper>
          </CheckIcon>
        </CustomCheckBox>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    )
  }
}
export default CheckBox
```

Copy Past this Component

Answer (score 0):

you can use [eact-native-elements checkbox](https://react-native-training.github.io/react-native-elements/API/checkbox/) uses vector icons and you can set colors

Answer (score 0):

You could use **Native Base**'s or **React-Native-Elements'** checkboxes. These are React-Native libraries of components, so they might come in handy for you in the future as well.

[Native Base's checkbox](https://docs.nativebase.io/Components.html#checkbox-headref)

[React-Native-Elements' checkbox](https://react-native-training.github.io/react-native-elements/API/checkbox/)

Comment: Thank you Eduard.

Comment: @BhavanPatel no problem ;)